# How to access incoming Servlet data with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, google-visualization

I'm making a web app, actually using Java EE, so the pattern is like this.
A query is sent to the DataBase from a DAO pattern.
the result of the query is passed to the controller, and the controller ( servlet ) passes the result query to the view which is a JSP page.

I have been using Expression Language to manipulate the incoming servlet data, but now as i want to manipulate a googlechart code to make statistics, i need to know how can i collect data with Javascript.

**Here are some details:**

This is the DAO part, selecting the type of tickets and counting them.

```
private static final String JPQL_SELECT_TICKETS_ETAT = "SELECT t.etat, COUNT(t.id_ticket) FROM Ticket t GROUP BY t.etat";

@PersistenceContext( unitName = "bdd_helpdesk_PU" )
private EntityManager       em;


public List<Object[]> chargerTicketsParEtat() throws DAOException {
    List<Object[]> liste;
    //List<Object[]> results = em.createQuery("").getResultList();
    TypedQuery<Object[]> query = em.createQuery(JPQL_SELECT_TICKETS_ETAT, Object[].class);
    //query.setParameter(PARAM_TICKET, id_ticket);
    try {
        liste = (List<Object[]>) query.getResultList();
    } catch ( NoResultException e ) {
        return null;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new DAOException(e);
    }
    return liste;
}
```

Next code happens in servlet:

```
        List<Object[]> lticket = ticketDao.chargerTicketsParEtat();
        String test= "this is a string";
        request.setAttribute("test", test);
        request.setAttribute("lticket",lticket);
```

And this is the JSP page:

The result is represented in numbers in a table like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Etat ticket</th>
<th>Nombre</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach items="${lticket}" var="ticket">
<tr>
<td>${ticket[0]}</td>
<td>${ticket[1]}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

And this is the kind of hart i'm going to use:

```
  <head>
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
  // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
  // draws it.
  function drawChart() {

    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
    data.addRows([
      ['Mushrooms', 3],
      ['Onions', 1],
      ['Olives', 1],
      ['Zucchini', 1],
      ['Pepperoni', 2]
    ]);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                   'width':400,
                   'height':300};

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

How is it possible to collect the lticket data so i can place them in the googlechart code.

Comment: Only two days left before the memoire deadline ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I did it in my project was to convert `List<Object[]> lticket` to JSON using Gson library and pass it to JSP using `request.setAttribute("lticketJson", json)`. You can then consume it in your JSP like `chart.draw(${lticketJson}, options);`

The other option is to prepare REST endpoint using JAX-RS capabilities that would server only the JSON and consume result using JavaScript fetch() or similar.